# Remove html output from xp:callback

Tags: xpages

I have  custom control containing some action buttons. Some are application wide and other are specific for a certain page. The specific buttons are being added using an editable area (

Is there a way to remove this generate div tag or should I just live with it and change a bit of css code ;)

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can remove the generated div tag by removing the `id` attribute and setting the `disableTheme` to `true` for `xp:callback`. So it would look something like this:

`<xp:callback facetName="facet_2" disableTheme="true"></xp:callback>`